# Looping through JS Array speed drops for 16383 items

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance, v8

While doing some benchmarks I've noticed that when you have array of length 16383 and above, speed looping through them (using for or Array.map) drops significantly compared to <=16382.

I'm curious why is this happening? Why for array length close to 2^14?

Here is some simple benchmark: https://jsperf.com/array-map-on-different-lengths When you run this, expected result would be, that speed will be declining slowly, but between 16382 and 16383 is ~25% drop.

And I've done some desktop tests with benchmark module, some results are here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dSIKjap6D38dIj00adaFAVmmO1mWbRJwKrDCsSVODQA/edit?usp=sharing

There is also visible drop for length of 16376 items.

Just creating arrays of different lengths and looping through them:

```js
const a = Array(16383).fill(1)
a.map(b => b)
```

Does this have something with heap, or some optimizations of V8?

I'm really curious. I'd look into source code, but don't even know where to start.

### Explanation (or how to call it)

Observed behavior is NOT caused by looping, it's caused by allocation of Arrays of certain lenghts. [image: Speed of allocating Array by length]

There can be some "breakpoints" observed.

- Around Array(**16**), 16 is lot faster than 17. [image: 16]
- Some weird things happening for Array(**1024**), which is a bit faster than before and after [image: 1024]
- And the already mentioned Array(**16383**) [image: 16383]

Comment: how many times you ran it?

Comment: Given you're not just looping, but with `map` also creating a new array, it's quite likely that you'e hit a boundary where (re)allocation of the result array works differently.

Comment: @VoidSpirit I've run it tens of times, and well, the benchmark is running every suite tens or hundreds of times.

Comment: @Bergi That would make sense, I'll try to just loop (forEach) through, which should result in no drop.

Comment: @Bergi you're right, of course, witch forEach, there is no difference. So actually I should just test `array.push(1)` on arrays of different sizes to see where reallocation is happening, and probably also with different content of the arrays, I guess.

Comment: Especially with `forEach`, make sure that [the empty loop doesn't get optimised away](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html) though

Comment: @Bergi thanks for pointing to this interesting article. In the meantime I've checked what are the costs of allocating different sizes of arrays, and pushing to them.

Comment: @ra100 Be sure to [let us know about your results](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :-)

Comment: @Bergi I'll need to do some more benching to not just to totally wrong conclusions like I've already done before :) I think I'll have some new graphs tomorrow. From preliminary tests it looks like `Array(16)` is 10-20x times faster than `Array(17)`.

Comment: @Bergi I've updated Question with some other observed behaviors. With links to graphs.

Comment: This could very likely be https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=9302